# can't get imageUrl of profileUser when I'm logging the firt time in firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have a problem when I loggin the first time, imageUrl from profile user can't load, then when I close the app and start it again, I get the imageUrl because the user is already logged. I don't know why I can not get the imageUrl at beggining if user logged.

```
FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
        Object does not exist at location.
         Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
```

```
private val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
private val storeRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

override suspend fun initProfile() : Resource<Uri> {

        val imageUriUrl = storeRef.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://pruebamultimedialab.appspot.com/")
            .child("images/${auth.currentUser?.uid}")
            .downloadUrl.await()

        return Resource.Success(imageUriUrl)
    }
```

This is my code to get ImageUrl from Firebase and its working fine.
The problem is when I signIn the firts time. I don't know what to do.

Also the rules from cloud:

```
  rules_version = '2';
    service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
            match /{allPaths=**} {
                allow read, write;
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling this function after user successfully logs in? May be you're calling this function before the user even logs in.

Comment: Just as the error says, try to log in first before calling the function. Also, are you using the `launch` builder for coroutine since you have a suspended function?

Comment: @SkSuraj Well, I'm calling this funtion in ProfileFragment. Logs in was in LogginFragment just before jump to this Fragment, and also check with auth.currentUser is not null.

Comment: @princessdharmy Yes I use launch in muy ViewModel to call this suspend funtion

Comment: As I know activity doesn't executes it's fragments one by one. If your fragments are in one single activity all fragments starts executing at the same time. So how do you know the profile fragment is starts executing after the login fragment executes?

Comment: @SkSuraj I was thinking about that, you are alright i think. I don't know how handle it. Maybe I could make an Activity to hold fragments (Register_Login and Reset) and other to  hold MainFragment and profileFragment. Can I use Navigation Component like this? I don't know if is a good practice...

Comment: Using Navigation component might not really solve the issue. What is mostly done is to have a different activity for authentication like Login, SignUp, OnBoarding. Then takes you to the main activity of the app.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Navigation component might not really solve the issue. What is
>   mostly done is to have a different activity for authentication like
>   Login, SignUp, OnBoarding. Then takes you to the main activity of the
>   app. – princessdharmy

- 1 Activity to hold : Login, Register and Reset fragments
- 2 activity to hold : profile, Main, etc.. fragments of main app.

Yes, I'm doing like that, is the best way to do it, because I saw conditional Navigation, and is a little complicated. Thanks for your answer @princessdharmy and @Sk Suraj.